# Divisibility of coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$ with fixed composite $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

To begin with recall a few facts about polynomials having all coefficients $1$, and their irreducibility or otherwise, and a relation to binomial coefficients.

If $n$ is composite then the polynomial $Q_n=(x^n-1)/(x-1)$ is reducible, since if $n=ab$ it is divisible by $(x^a-1)/(x-1),$ the other factor a sum of powers of $x^a$. 
On the other hand if $n$ is  a prime $p$ then $Q_p$ is irreducible, and the usual proof of this relies on substituting $x=u+1$ and applying Eisenstein's test using the prime $p$, noting that the integers in the set 
$$C_p=\{ \binom{p}{k} :1 \le k \le n-1\}$$ 
of "internal binomial coefficients" are each divisible by $p$, but the first and last are not divisible by $p^2,$ so that Eisenstein applies to the polynomial $Q_p$ in the new variable $u$.

*A consequence for composite $n$*

Now suppose that $n$ is composite and there is some prime $q$ for which $q|n$ but $q^2 $ does not divide $n.$ Then if the set of binomial coefficients $C_n$ were all divisible by $q$ it would follow that the Eisenstein argument would apply to $Q_n$. The conclusion is that $q$ cannot divide each binomial coefficient in $Q_n$. 
As a corollary, if $n$ is composite and squarefree, it follows that the internal binomial coefficents of $C_n$ have the g.c.d $1$ as a set. (This does not mean they are coprime in pairs!)

*The "question" I'm interested in:*

My question is as to whether the above facts about binomial coefficients might have a more direct / elementary proof, not using the machinery of irreducible polynomials and Eisenstein. I'd appreciate also any other proofs along different lines, even if using other "advanced" methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier way is to note that for $p$ prime and $m$ coprime to $p$, in particular 
$$
\binom{pm}{p} = \frac{pm\cdot (pm-1) \cdots (p(m-1)+1)}{p!}
$$
cannot be divisible by $p$, since the numerator conains precisely one power of $p$, as does the denominator.

Comment: Nice answer +1, although mine works too

Comment: This makes the machinery I used seem roundabout! +1

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be a prime and $k$ coprime to $p$, we will prove there is a solution to $p\nmid\binom{pk}{j}$ with $j\neq pk,0$

let $p^n$ be the largest power of $p$ smaller than $pk$, then $\binom{pk}{p^n}$ is not a multiple of $p$ why? notice $p^n+k\equiv k\bmod p^n$ ands since no number is disible by $p$ more than $n$ times this is sufficient.

The idea is that the numerator is $1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot \dots p^n\cdot (p^n+1)\cdot (p^n+2)\dots pk$

and the denominator is $1\cdot2\cdot3\dots p^n\cdot 1\cdot2\cdot3\dots(p^k-p^n)$

but the terms are congruent mod $p^n$ and this gives us all the divisibility information we need, since no number is divisible by $p$ more than $n$ times.